# IT characteristic implementation of motor protection circuit

Tags: motor, protection, current-limiting

I am trying to implement The IT - characteristic feature for motor protection device.There are 2C,5C,10C curve feature . can someone suggest me how it can be implemented in C code.

Is there any example code available.

1) what is effect of current setting on above curve based on 2.5C/5C/10C curve
2) Is there any equation available for time Vs current

Setting current as below

```
 under current limit  0.2 -25A
 overload current limit 0.2 -25A
 Short circuit limit   0.2A -50A
 Locked Rotor current limit 0.2A-50A
```

I find solution for IT characteristic.  this sample example given here. need c code

assume Overload current = 10A(user defined setting)

Over load current trip time =10s(user defined setting)

if curve 2C is selected

calculation are as below   The relay should turn on 30% over load trip time i.e 13A

```
Trip_Time  over_current
10  10
9   10.3
8   10.6
7   10.9
6   11.2
5   11.5
4   11.8
3   12.1
2   12.4
1   12.7
0   13
```

in code if the Nominal current exceeds overload current these are trip timing for relay. The timing and current will change as per user defined setting. can some one guide me C code.

[image: It characteristic]

Comment: The information you need will be in the motor's datasheet. If it isn't, choose a motor with a better datasheet.

Comment: this for an application development. like motor protection relay unit for pump control application. End customer can use motor on his relevant .i wanted to control starter output through relay. it will have external ct to measure under,overload,rotor lock,dry run case. so i can get data sheet for motor reference.